# input type date to set date which is fetch from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I have database **user** consist of attribute like **name,password,dob and etc.**
datatype is used to store date is **date**.while updating, I used to fetch like below

```
$query="select * from user where email='$user'";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$fet=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php if($fet['dob']==00-00-0000){ }else{ echo date($fet['dob']);} ?>">
```

I want date which is to fetch from database to this above input type date.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com learn about prepared statements and SQL injection if you not want your whole database to be deleted. Your code isn't safe at all.

Comment: i am new learner please help me out for this

Comment: What is wrong with your code ? What is the actual output ? And stop saying "please help", that's annoying.

Comment: In input type date not fetching date

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
As I understood in comments of my answer, you are storing `DATETIME` values in your database and not `DATE` values. Here is how to get a *date* format from a *datetime* format using `DateTime`class:

```
$dob = new DateTime($fet['dob']);
$formatted = $dob->format('Y-m-d');
```

To output it in short syntax in your `<input>`:

```
<?php
$dob = (new DateTime($fet['dob']))->format('Y-m-d');
?>
<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>">
```

---

**Issues**:
An [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) should have a value in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
The [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects a **format** and a **[timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)**.
You did not quote the `00-00-0000` value.

You won't need to format your **date** string as its format is right for your input:

```
<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $fet['dob']; ?>">
```

If you need to manipulate dates in PHP I would recommend the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: @MuraliManoj Do you make a loop to write the inputs ? `mysqli_fetch_array()` is returning a multidimensionnal array, at least try to echo `$fet[0]['dob']`.

Comment: @MuraliManoj Could you explain a bit, saying "not working" does not help... What is wrong ? Do you get an error ? What does `echo '<pre>' . print_r($fet, true) . '</pre>';` outputs ? What does `var_dump($fet[0]['dob']);` outputs ?

Comment: when I print $fet['dob'];  it will print like this 2018-06-21 02:08:02 when I had a value to input type date, the printed date should be selected automatically in input type date right, it is not working

Comment: @MuraliManoj it wasn't working because you said you were storing `DATE` type in database but you are storing `DATETIME` values. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

> I used to fetch like below

What you've shown is not valid PHP - it won't work. PHP will tell you when stuff is not working and why if your error logging/reporting is configured correctly.

> input type="date"

I presume you are aware this has very limited support in browsers

> select *

Generally its a very bad idea not to be specific about what you are selecting from a database, and particularly so in this scenario. Even if the underlying data type for the dob is a date, you should do an explicit format on it to get it into the right form for the later processing (in this case, injecting it as the value of the input)